# Apply and Clear ColorFilter on view in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button, effects, colorfilter

I have 2 buttons with different parents.

I am trying to apply button effect onTouch of the button.

Here is my code:

```
public class ButtonHighlighterOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    final Button button;

    public ButtonHighlighterOnTouchListener(final Button imageButton) {
      super();
      this.button = imageButton;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#B7B2B0"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            button.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            button.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            button.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            button.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            button.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return false;
        }
}
```

It applies the effect to the button, but the problem is since I have 2 buttons, even when I click on one button, the effect is being applied to the other button as well.

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 7):

`view`in `onTouch`method is, in your case, the `Button`is being clicked. So instead of

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#B7B2B0"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

use

```
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#B7B2B0"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

And the same in other cases of switch.

**Edit**

Instead, use styles:

```
//background_button.xml in drawable folder
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    //Here you can set style you want when Button is pressed
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#22228C" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#9999DE" />
            <corners
                android:radius="7dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
    //Here you can set style you want when button is not pressed
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#5858C8"
                android:endColor="#22228C"
                android:angle="90" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#9999DE" />
            <corners
                android:radius="7dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

//In your xml
<Button
     android:background="@drawable/background_button" ... />
```

**Edit 2**

`Button`has a constructor where you can tell which style you want to apply.

```
public Button (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle);
```

So you can set `defStyle = android.R.style.Button` and in your `styles.xml`add

```
<style name="Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_button</item>
</style>
```

With that, I think you could initialize your `Button`with the style (where you will have your highlighted effect in `background_button.xml`) and add background image as you have right now.

Comment: And why not using styles?

Comment: how?,i have do it progrmatically only

Comment: yes, but here i am creating button programatically and i have set the button.setBackgroundDrawable already so how can i integrate now?

Comment: i tried your code,it works fine, can you please help me acheive the same progrmatically

Comment: by default it will have an image and when pressed the highlighted effect on that image

Comment: Is that image same to all buttons you want the highlighted effect?

Comment: yes, the image for all buttons will be same but the highlight color will be light gray,can you please help me out to do it progrmatically

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36526/discussion-between-goofy-and-lyd)

Comment: why do you use "Color.parseColor" ? isn't it the same as just adding "0xff" before the value?

Answer (score 4):

**Try :** replacing **button with view** and **return true instead of false**;

```
public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            view .getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#B7B2B0"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            view .invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            view .getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            view .invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            view .getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            view .invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way:

There are two ways to apply color filter on view.

```
private ImageView imageView;

imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

### Apply color filter

**Way 1:**

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

#### OR

**Way 2:**

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

### Clear color filter

```
imageView.clearColorFilter();
```

Both are work fine for me.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work on `BottomNavigationView`?